# reading name contact

Tags: java, swing, contacts

Im making a contact list, and my code compiles and runs, when you add the contact, type or email or phone its supposed to read them to you, the problem I have here is when I add the contacts and press next or previous, first or last it doesnt read the Name Contact, but it reads everything else...does it have to do something with spacing ? here is what I have...thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;



 public class ContactSystem extends JFrame{
//Specify the size of five string fields in the record
final static int NAME_SIZE = 32;
final static int TYPE_SIZE = 32;
final static int CITY_SIZE = 20;
final static int PHONE_SIZE = 15;
final static int EMAIL_SIZE = 15;
final static int RECORD_SIZE =
        (NAME_SIZE + TYPE_SIZE + CITY_SIZE + PHONE_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE);

//access contact.dat using RandomAccessFile
private RandomAccessFile raf;

//Text Fields
private JTextField jbtName = new JTextField(NAME_SIZE);
private JTextField jbtType = new JTextField(TYPE_SIZE);
private JTextField jbtCity = new JTextField(CITY_SIZE);
private JTextField jbtPhone = new JTextField(PHONE_SIZE);
private JTextField jbtEmail = new JTextField(EMAIL_SIZE);

//Buttons
private JButton jbtAdd = new JButton("Add");
private JButton jbtFirst = new JButton("First");
private JButton jbtNext = new JButton("Next");
private JButton jbtPrevious = new JButton("Previous");
private JButton jbtLast = new JButton("Last");

public ContactSystem(){
    //open or create a random access file

    try {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile("contact.txt", "rw");
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.print("Error: " + ex);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Panel p1 for holding labels Name , Type, Email or phone
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    p1.add(new JLabel("Name Contact"));
    p1.add(new JLabel("Email Address"));
    p1.add(new JLabel("Type of Contact"));

    //Panel jpPhone for holding Phone
    JPanel jpPhone = new JPanel();
    jpPhone.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jpPhone.add(new JLabel("Phone"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    jpPhone.add(jbtPhone, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Panel jpEmail for holding Phone
    JPanel jpEmail = new JPanel();
    jpEmail.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jpEmail.add(new JLabel("Phone"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    jpEmail.add(jbtEmail, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Panel p2 for holding jpPhone and jpEmail
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p2.add(jpPhone, BorderLayout.WEST);
    p2.add(jpPhone, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    p3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p3.add(jbtCity, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p3.add(p2, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //panel p4 for holding jtfName, jtfType, and p3
    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    p4.add(jbtName);
    p4.add(jbtType);
    p4.add(p3);

    //place p1 and p4 into jpContact
    JPanel jpContact = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    jpContact.add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    jpContact.add(p4, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //set panel with line border
    jpContact.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));

    //add buttons to a panel
    JPanel jpButton = new JPanel();
    jpButton.add(jbtAdd);
    jpButton.add(jbtFirst);
    jpButton.add(jbtNext);
    jpButton.add(jbtPrevious);
    jpButton.add(jbtLast);

    //add jpContact and jpButton to the frame

    add(jpContact, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jpButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jbtAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            writeContact();

        }
    });
    jbtFirst.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                if (raf.length() > 0) readContact(0);
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    jbtNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                long currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                if (currentPosition < raf.length())
                    readContact(currentPosition);

            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    jbtPrevious.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                long currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                if(currentPosition - 2 * RECORD_SIZE > 0)
                    //why 2 * 2 * RECORD_SIZE? see the the follow-up remarks
                    readContact(currentPosition - 2 * 2 * RECORD_SIZE);
                else
                    readContact(0);

            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    jbtLast.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                long lastPosition = raf.length();
                if(lastPosition > 0)
                    //why 2 * RECORD_SIZE? see the follow up remarks
                    readContact(lastPosition - 2 * RECORD_SIZE);

            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        if (raf.length() > 0) readContact(0);

    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }


}

//write a record at the end of file

public void writeContact() {

    try {
        raf.seek(raf.length());
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(
                jbtName.getText(), NAME_SIZE, raf);
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(
                jbtType.getText(), TYPE_SIZE, raf);
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(
                jbtCity.getText(), CITY_SIZE, raf);
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(
                jbtPhone.getText(), PHONE_SIZE, raf);
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(
                jbtEmail.getText(), EMAIL_SIZE, raf);

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//read a contact at the specific position
public void readContact(long position) throws IOException{
    raf.seek(position);
    String name = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
            NAME_SIZE, raf);
    String type = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
            TYPE_SIZE, raf);
    String city = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
            CITY_SIZE, raf);
    String phone = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
            PHONE_SIZE, raf);
    String email = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
            EMAIL_SIZE, raf);

    jbtName.setText(name);
    jbtType.setText(type);
    jbtCity.setText(city);
    jbtName.setText(phone);
    jbtName.setText(email);

}



/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContactSystem frame = new ContactSystem();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle("Contact System");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

fixedlengthstringIO class

```
  import java.io.*;


  public class FixedLengthStringIO {

//read fixed number of characters from datainput stream
public static String readFixedLengthString(int size,
        DataInput in) throws IOException {
    //declare an array of characters
    char[] chars = new char[size];

    //read fixed number of characters to the array
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        chars[i] = in.readChar();
    return new String (chars);
}

//write fixed number of characters to a dataoutput stream

public static void writeFixedLengthString(String s, int size,
        DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    char[] chars = new char[size];

    //fill an array of characters from the string
    s.getChars(0, Math.min(s.length(), size), chars, 0);

    //fill in blank characters in the rest of the array
    for (int i = Math.min(s.length(), size); i < chars.length; i++)
        chars[i] = ' ';

    //create and write a new string padded with blank characters
    out.writeChars(new String(chars));
}
}
```

here is when I type in contact name, type, email etc into the list

[image]

and when I press next or previous, or first or last, it doesnt read the name..

[image]

Comment: Please reduce your code to the specific part that doesn't do what it should. Explain us what it's supposed to do, and what it does instead. Preferrably with example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glitch is in your `readContact` method, change this

```
 public void readContact(long position) throws IOException {
        raf.seek(position);
        String name = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
                NAME_SIZE, raf);
        String type = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
                TYPE_SIZE, raf);
        String city = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
                CITY_SIZE, raf);
        String phone = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
                PHONE_SIZE, raf);
        String email = FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(
                EMAIL_SIZE, raf);

        jbtName.setText(name);
        jbtType.setText(type);
        jbtCity.setText(city);
        jbtPhone.setText(phone);
        jbtEmail.setText(email);

    }
```

Also instead of adding separate `ActionListner` command button you can implement like

```
public class ContactSystem extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
  .....
  jbtAdd.addActionListener(this);
  jbtFirst.addActionListener(this);
  .....

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
    if(actionCommand.equals("Add")) {
        //do add stuff
    } else if (actionCommand.equals("First")) {
        // move first
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Also instead of adding separate `ActionListner` command button you can implement like"*  Yes you can, but people are typically recommending to add a separate `ActionListener` or `Action` for each button/menu item that needs them.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes thompson, I've read some documents. you are correct. thanks.